# Add a legend using the plotly scatter matrix API?

Tags: python, plotly

The following describes pretty well how to make a scatter matrix:

https://plotly.com/python/splom/#scatter-matrix-splom-with-gosplom

But nowhere does it mention legend. If I set `showlegend=True` I only get "trace 0" (i.e. the generic name of the Plotly trace) instead of the actual category names. I can't seem to figure out where to put in my category array without crashing the plot.

If I take the `index_vals` array shown in the examples for colors, and place it in e.g. `legendgroup=index_vals` I get `ValueError: Invalid value of type 'pandas.core.series.Series' received for the 'legendgroup'`.

How should it be done?